# Replacing values for a particular key in treemap changes values for every key

Tags: java, collections, treemap

For some reason when I change a value for a particular key in my tree-map every key value changes for some reason. Here's the code snippet,

```
ArrayList<Integer> bitor = new ArrayList<>();
TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList> a = new TreeMap<>();
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    bitor.add(0);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    a.put(i, bitor);
}
System.out.println(a);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    x = i;
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        if(x!=j)
        {
            y = j;
            for(int k=0; k<n; k++)
            {
                if(x!=k && y!=k)
                {
                    z = k;
                    System.out.println(a);
                    bitor = a.get(x);
                    if(bitor.get(0)==3)
                        break;
                    System.out.println(1+" "+x+" "+y+" "+z);
                    System.out.flush();
                    bitor.set(0, bitor.get(0)+1);
                    ans = sc.nextInt();
                    if(ans==-1)
                        System.exit(ans);
                    bitor.set(bitor.get(0), ans);
                    a.replace(x, bitor);
                }
                if(bitor.get(0)==3)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1wLw.png)

Only the arraylist value for key=0 was supposed to change but every key-value got changed.

This is kind of weird and I am guessing I am doing a silly mistake.

Comment: All your keys point to the same bitor-object.

Comment: But its only the first loop for i. And I am only trying to change value for i=0. 'i' didnt even increment.

Comment: Instead of posting an image of the output, can you copy the text from the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    a.put(i, bitor);
}
```

This doesn't do what you think it does.  Every key points to the same value.  You *must* create a new `bitor`, explicitly, for each `i`.

Comment: So even if I change the values in bitor and do not change the value for my map variable, every value still changes?

Comment: Correct.  Every one of those points to the same object.  There is no "every value," you have only made one value.

Comment: I see. Great help

Answer (score 4):

You should create a new ArrayList before adding it, since it **is not copied, but added as a reference** in your tree.

The easiest way to solve this, is to just change at the start:

```
TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList> a = new TreeMap<>();
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> bitor = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
        bitor.add(0);
    a.put(i, bitor);
}
```